# How to validate Path parameters?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, validation

I am working on plain node.js API (Lambda function) so here I have one event, in which I am passing path Parameters as:

const {empID} = event.pathParameters

Lets say my api is [https://something.com/api/{empID}](https://something.com/api/%7BempID%7D)

Now I want to validate that if empID is not passed or left blank like https://something.com/api/

So how to validate this can anyone please help me on that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's wrong with if statements?

Comment: but which condition should I use === null or === "" both are not working, Or may be I have done something wrong in it. Can you please let me know correct way. Thanks

Comment: probably undefined? you'd have to check the documentation of the lambda service you're using

Comment: I will look into lambda documentation. Thanks @bel3atar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to validate then you have to do it before the request reaches the node server. Because if you left blank like https://something.com/api/, then it will look for https://something.com/api/ this api instead of [https://something.com/api/{empID}](https://something.com/api/%7BempID%7D) this one. So validate in the front end where you are setting the value for {empID}.

And also instead of [https://something.com/api/{empID}](https://something.com/api/%7BempID%7D) try creating api as [https://something.com/api/employee/{empID}](https://something.com/api/employee/%7BempID%7D). Because if you have [https://something.com/api/{empID}](https://something.com/api/%7BempID%7D) and then again create another api [https://something.com/api/{customerID}](https://something.com/api/%7BcustomerID%7D), now when you try to hit [https://something.com/api/{customerID}](https://something.com/api/%7BcustomerID%7D) it will hit [https://something.com/api/{empID}](https://something.com/api/%7BempID%7D) instead. (whichever api is defined first)

Comment: Oh Thanks for explaining me the empID and customerID thing really appreciated.